# TypeScript - using Grunt to compile TypeScript in the background

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a web app with Node.js and some TypeScript files being used to create a more complex typesafe engine to do a lot of the work. This is conceptually pushing the boundaries of my understanding in several ways, but here are some assumptions:

- For development, when I am creating new TypeScript files, I need to recompile them to JavaScript every-time I test my program out.
- For production, I could deploy already compiled TypeScript ---> JavaScript, so I don't believe I will need to compile when the user is running the app.

I want to use Grunt to compile my TypeScript, if that's the best option. Are there any race condition to worry about when using

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-typescript

to compile into JavaScript, when other JavaScript files might require or call functions from my newly compiled TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

I use grunt and its alternative [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com/)(also you can take a look),and there is no need to concern about it. These tools will make easier dev js compile steps.

In first clause, there are a grunt or gulpjs watch plugins for compile automaticly when save your typescript code.

Also You're right in the second clause, you won't need to compile while user is running the app, you will just deploy javascript.